# rails-mysql rake db :create - Library not loaded libmysqlclient.20.dylib image not found

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

Reason: image not found - /Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Our application requires mysql version 5.6 which seems to be working ok -

```
$ mysql -uroot
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>
```

However when I try to create the database from rails I get:

```
$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/mysql2-0.3.20/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx/Rakefile:10:in `require'
/Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/mdurrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
14:18:13 mdurrant EQ-267 /Users/mdurrant/eq/lynx master
$
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The fix was to

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

then reinstall it again with

```
bundle  # gem install mysql2 would also work
```

This recompiles and resolves the reference that had been left over from having mysql 5.7.9 installed.

Comment: For those wondering what the _cause_ of this may be—My loose understanding is that it is related to the fact that when `mysql2` is installed, it creates native extensions for the  _current_ _Ruby_ _version (see `gems/ruby-2.1.5/extensions` in the stacktrace?). If you then change Ruby versions without re-installing `mysql2`, the existing natives extensions won't be able to find the image since it is still under the old Ruby version. So you should reinstall `mysql2` after changing ruby versions.

Comment: works on Apple M1 2021 after having fixed issues with multiple installations of mysql

Comment: In Django, I removed  'mysqlclient' then Reinstalled it fixed the problem !

Answer (score 1):

OS X is not able to find the libmysqlclient.18.dylib library. To make it accessible, We can do the following :

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

to your ~/.bash_profile, don't forget to source it after by running:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Comment: Add more detail to your answer and format it to make it more readable.